# Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be non zero matrices such that $AB-BA=A+B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be non zero matrices such that $AB-BA=A+B$. Then show that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ and $PBP^{-1}$ are both upper triangular matrices?

I have shown that $tr(A+B)^k$ is zero for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence $A+B$ is nilpotent. From this how to complete the problem

Comment: what happened to your question with two matrices with a common eigenvector?

Comment: @WillJagy it was deleted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212235 after I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. $\ker(A+B)\subseteq\ker(A+B)^2\subseteq\cdots$
2. On $\ker(A+B)$, $AB=BA$

Comment: can you please elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.* Let $C=[A,B]$. Use the condition $C=A+B$ to prove that $[A,C]=C$. Hence prove that $C$ is nilpotent and $\ker(C)$ is a non-trivial invariant subspace of $A$. It follows that $A$ and $C$ share a common eigenvector. Since $C=A+B$, this eigenvector is also shared by $B$. Now proceed recursively.

Comment: Would you please explain a little more

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $A$ and $B$ share a eigenvector $v$. The result then follows from recursion.
Let $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ and let $A_1=A-\lambda I$, $B_1=B+\lambda I$, then
$$A_1 B_1-B_1 A_1=AB-BA=A+B=A_1 + B_1$$
Right-multiply both side by $v$, then we have $A_1 B_1 v=B_1 v$, i.e.,
$$(A-(\lambda+1)I)B_1 v=0$$
This shows that either $B_1 v=0$ or $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda+1$. However, since $A$ has at most $n$ eigenvalues, there exist $\lambda^{\star}$ such that $\lambda^{\star}+1$ is not an eigenvalue. In this case, $v$ is the common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$.